# How do I estimate the Average Treatment Effect on the Treated in a Difference-In-Difference Model?

Tags: difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

Suppose the DID model is
Y = a + b(Treatment) +c(Time) + d(Treatment*Time). Now, If i wanted to find out the average treatment effect on the treated, how should i modify my model?

Comment: re-write it as Y = a + (b + d*time) Treatment + c Time?

Comment: Is that the correct format? Treatment will have only a single value then right?

Answer (score 0):

DID estimates the ATT. If treatment was randomized, then ATT=ATE=ATU.

Comment: Than you for the clarification Sir. Under DDD estimation, is it possible to check for the validity of parallel trend assumption?

Comment: You can check that it holds pre-treatment. But you need it to hold in the post-treatment period, which is not verifiable. The hope is that if it worked before, it works later, so it's a half-test.

Comment: But what if our dataset is a panel data of just two time periods? How would we check for the parallel trend assumption under Triple Difference Estimation then?

Comment: With two periods, you can't do it at all. You should start another question since this discussion has little to do with your original question or my answer to it.